# How to display postmeta key and value in same post id wordpress (JSON data)

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

in there i have data postmeta i want to show

```html
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'product'
                        // 'showposts'    => 4,
                        // 'meta_key'     => '_sale_price', 
                        // 'meta_value'   => '0', 
                        // 'meta_compare' => '>=',
                    )
                ); 
if($loop->have_posts()) :

    $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

           $data[] = array("id" => get_the_ID(),
          "post_name" => get_the_title(),
          "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

    endwhile;


    echo  json_encode($data);
break;
}
```

in there i want to show data :

[image]

where the meta data have same post id data,

i want to loop the data in inside details, have someone help me or tell me what code need i improve so my code its work ?

Comment: Wait, so you just wanna get this as JSON?

Comment: sure.. have u can help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta data is storing in **wp_postmeta** table. Use json_encode.

You can fetch meta by `$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );`

Please check following code .

```
if($loop->have_posts()) :

    $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

           $data[] = array("id" => get_the_ID(),
          "post_name" => get_the_title(),
          "post_meta" => get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

    endwhile;


    echo  json_encode($data);
```

Comment: sure, i know that but how i can get the data as JSON data ?

i mean how to make it ? in inside details ?

Comment: i get blank response, could u check my code did its wrong ? i update my question.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you just want your table data as json, then you just need to use `json_encode()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
if( $loop->have_posts() ) :

    $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
    $meta = array();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $meta[] = array(
            "id"         => get_the_ID(),
            "post_name"  => get_the_title(),
            "_edit_lock" => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_edit_lock', true ),
            "_edit_last" => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_edit_last', true ),
            "username"   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'username', true ),
            "password"   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'password', true ),
            "email"      => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email', true ),
            "phone"      => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'phone', true ),
        );

    endwhile;
endif;

echo  json_encode($meta);
```

Comment: thanks, may ask something ? how i give a parameter(for access this data) in there sorry out of topic, parameter `the id post`

Comment: sorry if misrepresented, i mean when i want to access this data i need to input id first ,

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you asking about how to access the JSON data? or showing the sample code what you trying would also help.

Comment: its already help me but (showing data about pos_type = product) then i want go give more spesific like before i can access the data i need to input the ID
for example : i input id : 49 so the data only show data with id 49